# angularjs - Dynamic ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**The main thing i want is if my database < table < field `paid` is '0' the button should display and if `paid` is '1' then the text sub should display.**

JavaScript Code

```
<script>
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = [],
    hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
var user = getUrlVars()["user"];
var pass = getUrlVars()["pass"];
//document.write.phn;
</script>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('dropdownCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', function($scope, $window, $http) {
  //window.location.reload();
  $http.get('http://dummy.com/dashboard.php?user=' + user + '&pass=' + pass).then(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response.data.admin;
  });
  $scope.names = [];
  $scope.subs = function() {
    $http.post('http://dummy.com/subs-req.php?user=' + user + '&pass=' + pass);
  }
}]);
</script>
```

HTML Code

```html
<div ng-if="names.paid = 0">
   <button ng-click="subs()" style="color:#fff;margin-right:20px;float:right;border-radius:5px;border:none;padding:10px;background:#f9a806;">
   Subscription Request</button><br /><br />
</div>
<div ng-if="names.paid = 1">
   sub
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if=names.paid = 0" use === instead of one equal.

Comment: did not work...

Comment: If `paid` is the string `'0'`, then it would need to be `ng-if="names.paid === '0'"`  (Note the single quotes.)  This would be something to fix too, using a string as a boolean is not great.

Comment: still didn't work.. i did the whole thing you said

Comment: You'll need to use your debugging skills. Find out what the value of `names.paid` is, because it's not `'0'` if you used that.  Also check the console for any errors.

Comment: holy mother of dangerous code, look at the username/password being passed in the URLs. the horror

Comment: In reality i didn't even try to read the code, i just eanted to look at html since they are the only readable things in the question lol...